# How to set the DataContext.CommandTimeout application wide

Tags: vb.net, linq, datacontext, command-timeout

I want to set the timeout for my `DataContext Class` application wide. I can find a lot of examples for C# ([1](http://smsohan.com/blog/2008/04/29/how-to-set-default-application-wide/), [2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26283/Change-The-Default-CommandTimeout-of-LINQ-DataCont?fid=1342163&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=26#xx0xx)) translated to `vb.net` it would be

```
Partial Class SampleDBDataContext
    Inherits System.Data.Linq.DataContext
    Partial Private Sub OnCreated()
        'Put your desired timeout here.
        Me.CommandTimeout = 3600
    End Sub
End Class
```

But it gives the error: `Class '<classname1>' must declare a 'Sub New' because its base class '<classname2>' has more than one accessible 'Sub New' that can be called with no arguments.`

**I have two questions now:**
I am just not able to solve the `"sub new"` problem. If I put a

```
Sub New()
End Sub
```

I get the error that this constructor doesnt exit but I am not sure what existing constructor I should use since I never used a `Partial Class` before.

The second is that I am not sure what `SampleDBDataContext` I have to use since I have a solution called MySolution where I have a `MySolution.SampleDBDataContext` and I also have `System.Date.Linq.DataContext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that you need to create partial class for `DataContext` class generated from `.dbml`. The newly created partial need to have corresponding namespace and name as the auto-generated one so that they can be recognized as one unit of class.

Once your class recognized as partial of the auto-generated `DataContext` class, you don't even need to manually inherits `System.Data.Linq.DataContext`, because the auto-generated one already inherits `System.Data.Linq.DataContext`.

Regarding the error message :

> Class `'<classname1>'` must declare a 'Sub New' because its base class `'<classname2>'` has more than one accessible 'Sub New' that can be called with no arguments.

that's because `SampleDBDataContext` inherits `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` without providing constructor (`Sub New`). The base class doesn't have parameterless constructor -which is the default constructor to call upon intialization of the class- so that compiler can't infer which parameterized constructor should it call and how the parameters should be supplied. The solution in this case isn't to provide constructor in your partial class, but to have it corresponds to the correct 'other side' of partial class, that is the autogenerated one. Auto-generated `DataContext` has all constructors needed declared so that your partial class doesn't have obligation to provide one.

Comment: Hi! Thans a lot for your answer! I did of lot of research on my solution and I found out that there is no .dbml and I only have one commandtimeout property in system.linq.datacontext. So there is no auto-generated one. Maybe it has something to do with my architechture? I have an SQL-Server with stored procedure. I fill a dataset with the SP's output and query a datatable with LINQ.

Comment: @ruedi I assumed you're using LINQ-to-SQL, like the one in this blog post and it has .dbml: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/using-linq-to-sql-part-1 , no? So what is it you're using?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. I use Linq to Dataset and found a solution that helped me get things done (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13009/Accesing-CommandTimeout-properties-in-a-TableAdapt). Nonetheless is your answer the solution to the problem in the question. Thanks!